# getting 404 error while developing an example module

Tags: 8

I have created custom module named hello 
my files are

**hello.info.yml**  is

```
name: Hello 
type: module 
description: 'My first Drupal 8 module.' 
package: Awesome modules 
version: 1.0 
core: '8.x'
```

**hello.module** file is

```
<?php 

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface; 
function hello_hello_world() {    

    return t('Hello Drupal 8 World!'); 

}
```

** hello.routing.yml** file is

```
hello.content:   
  path: '/hello'   
    defaults:     
       _controller: '\Drupal\hello\Controller\HelloController::sayhello'   
  requirements:     
    _permission: 'access content'
```

and last one is **HelloController.php** is under hello/src/Controller folder

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\hello\Controller;
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

/**
 *
 */
class HelloController extends ControllerBase {
    /**
     * [sayhello description]
     * @return [type] [description]
     */
    public function sayhello() {
        return array('#markup' => hello_hello_world());
    }
}
```

when we browse this page mywebsite.com/hello it gives a `404 error` page.

**Note:** module is successfully enabled from admin

Comment: I think `_permission: 'TRUE'` is not a valid thing. You need to use a permission name, such as `_permission: 'access content'`

Comment: no its still 404

Comment: Is help.routing.yml  the name of the routing file of yours? It should be hello.routing.yml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The indentation of your hello.routing.yml file is wrong. It should be as the following one. (See [user.routing.yml](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21user.routing.yml/8.2.x).)

```
user.pass:
  path: '/user/password'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\user\Form\UserPasswordForm'
    _title: 'Reset your password'
  requirements:
    _access: 'TRUE'
  options:
    _maintenance_access: TRUE
```

Indentation in YAML files is very important, since it changes the file content.

Notice that you can use `_access: 'TRUE'`, when the page doesn't require a specific permission. The `_maintenance_access: TRUE` line is not necessary. If you use it, users have access to your route even when the site is in maintenance mode; other requirements are still respected, so you could have something similar to the following.

```
user.login:
  path: '/user/login'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\user\Form\UserLoginForm'
    _title: 'Log in'
  requirements:
    _user_is_logged_in: 'FALSE'
  options:
    _maintenance_access: TRUE
```

Before making any changes, uninstall the module, fix the file, and re-install the module.

As side note, you don't need the `use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface;` line in your hello.module file, since you aren't using that PHP interface.

Answer (score 1):

**Couple of things which is wrong in the above code**:

- help.routing.yml should be renamed to hello.routing.yml
- Controller folder should be under src folder. Structure should be hello/src/Controller/HelloController.php.

Hope that making these changes help you to render the page without 404 error.